# Pasting a JSON file in browser does not work - getAsFile returns null

Tags: html, json, paste

I am trying to paste a JSON file into a web page, but `getAsFile()` returns null.

It works OK when pasting an image file.

It appears as though only image file content can be pasted, otherwise only the filename is pasted.

Is there any way to paste a non-image file?

The page happens to be a React page.

```
const handlePaste = (event: React.ClipboardEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < event.clipboardData.items.length; i++) {
    const item = event.clipboardData.items[i]

    if (item.getAsFile) {
      const file = item.getAsFile()

      if (file) {
        console.log('Name', file.name)
        console.log('Size', file.size)
      } else {
        console.log('File is null')
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Discarding image paste data', item.type)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's not possible. You have to use type='file' and upload it.